# Cordova InAppBrowser opens double window on Android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have developed an app in Cordova 3.6 with latest version of InAppBrowser. Run on Android device (4.1.2 and others) when the user taps a link to open InAppBrowser, occasionally a double window seems to open up. The second of these windows doesn't close.

To check if it was something I had done in my app, I quickly created a default Cordova hello world app and added the standard window.open code with link like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank')">OPEN WINDOW</a>
```

and basic testing on the device revealed the same thing was happening - occasionally fast or double tapping made a double window open up, one of which was uncloseable. Either from <300ms double tap, or from double taps where the browser is slow to launch.

This doesn't appear to happen on iOS.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

UPDATE

Part of the problem on my main app was functions declared in wrong place (onpagecreate) being fired multiple times. I put this here in case someone does anything similar...

However on the hello world app the problem still occasionally happens. I tried with and without Fastclick, but Fastclick didn't work properly (possible conflict with jQuery Mobile, arrghh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is likely caused by using the 'onclick' event to launch the childbrowser.

onclick has a built in 300ms timeout, which can make an app appear laggy and causes some of the issues above.

Use mouseup/mousedown instead, and inside the handler, disable the listener

```
<a href="#" onclick="open('http://www.google.com','_blank')">OPEN WINDOW</a>

function open(url, name) {
    // deregister the onclick listener, insuring the callback resolves
    window.open(url,name);
    // register the listener
}
```

Comment: I had tried Fastclick, but didn't work properly, possibly due to jQuery Mobile conflict. Anyway, will investigate further, but this question may reduce to some others already on SO, so unless some more enlightenment comes, will mark you as answered.